# Java Eclipse Debug and Deploy Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, testing, deployment

I'm working on a big project and the test component is consumed me the most part of the time.
Why ? 
When I made some changes in a project during the debug, to suffer effect I have to stop the debug, deply and debug again. And I know if I change the configurations, I can do some changes during the debug. Anyone know what I need to do?

Another problem:
To do the deploy of some changes, how can I do without deploy all of the project ? This consume more than 7 minutes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Damian, JRebel should be the best solution for you. But it is not free and you need to pay to use it. Some Servers already have in some versions of it the functionality you want. Do a research about hot deploy.